# JavaScript RegEx buscar palabras que empiecen por X pero no mostrar X

Tags: javascript, regex

Hola estoy aprendiendo con las expresiones regulares y tengo dudas acerca de como resolver un problema de búsqueda. Me gustaría buscar, dentro de un string, todas las palabras que empiecen por una letra pero que a la hora de filtrar con las expresiones regulares no me muestre dicha letra. Os pongo un ejemplo:

usuario@gmail.com

Quiero buscar las palabras que terminen con un @ al final, pero a la hora de filtrarlo no me gustaría que saliese ese arroba

usuario @ gmail.com (algo así)

He probado con este código pero me muestra el arroba:

```
var respuesta = "usuario@gmail.com";
var filtro = /\w+@\b/;
var filtrado = respuesta.match(filtro);
alert(filtrado); // muestra usuario@
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola, ¿que tal si usas [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring) una vez que obtienes un `match` de tu regexp?. Por ejemplo: `var filtrado = filtrado.substring(0, filtrado.length - 1);`. Sabiendo que el último caracter no deseas mostrarlo, pues el método `substring()` usado así te devuelve todos los caracteres menos el último. Saludos

Comment: La regex es ` /\w+(?=@.+)/`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes al menos dos formas de hacerlo:

### Positive lookahead

Si en tu expresión regular pones `(?=<loquesea>)` se busca que, tras lo que haya encajado hasta ese punto, después aparezca `<loquesea>`, que es otra expresión regular, pero esta última, aunque se tiene en cuenta para ver si hay un *match*, no formará parte del *match* resultante.

Entonces, en tu caso, la arroba sería parte de un *positive lookahead*:

```
\w+(?=@)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUG7FA/1)

### Grupos de captura

Si pones algo entre paréntesis en tu expresión regular, ese algo será capturado en un grupo aparte del *match* total. Así que puedes poner entre paréntesis lo que aparezca delante de la arroba.

Es decir:

```
(\w+)@
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUG7FA/2)

En javascript puedes acceder a los grupos de captura tratando el resultado devuelto por *match* como un array. Su elemento 0 sería el *match* completo (incluirá la arroba), su elemento 1 sería el primer grupo de captura (no la incluirá).

```js
let str = 'usuario@gmail.com';

let result = str.match(/(\w+)@/);

console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result[1]);
```